# Programmatically Set Up UISlider Not Reacting to Input

Tags: xcode, uislider

I am attempting to set up a UISlider programmatically but cannot get it to work. On the one hand `slider.addTarget()` works perfectly. When I move the slider the function `rotateSlider(_:)` gets called perfectly.
On the other hand when I try to set the start value programmatically it does not move the handle. Also if I try to hide the slider with `slider.isHidden = true`, nothing happens and it is not removed from the view.

```
var slider1: UISlider {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40)
        let slider1 = UISlider(frame: frame)
        slider1.center = CGPoint(x: Int(self.view.frame.width) / 2, y: Int(self.view.frame.height) / 2)
        slider1.minimumValue = -3
        slider1.maximumValue = 3
        slider1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.rotateSlider(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
        return slider1
    }


@objc func rotateSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    print("rotated")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(slider1)
    slider1.setValue(1.0, animated: true) // This does not work
    slider1.isHidden = true // This does not work
}
```

I know it is something trivial that I am missing?!

Thanks.

Comment: `slider1` vs. `rotationSlider1`?

Comment: Sorry typo. I corrected it.